# JavaScript Socket.IO to Swift

Tags: javascript, swift, socket.io

I have this script and I need to know how to do this in swift. I can't seem to figure it out even with the documentation. I am using the `socket.io` client swift :

```
socket = io.connect('http://app.awesomepp.com:3000/chat', {
   query: "token=" + encodeURIComponent(auth_token),
   forceNew: true
});
```

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In swift 2.0:

```
socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: "http://app.awesomepp.com:3000/chat", opts: ["log": true, "connectParams": ["token":auth_token]])
```

Full Example (untested, but based on a working example):

```
import UIKit
import Socket_IO_Client_Swift

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var socket:SocketIOClient!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let auth_token = "this is my token"
    self.socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: "http://app.awesomepp.com:3000/chat", opts: ["log": true, "connectParams": ["token":auth_token]])

    addHandlers()
    self.socket.connect()
}

func addHandlers() {
    self.socket.on("connect") { data, ack in
        print("socket connected")
    }
}
}
```

Comment: thank you! This was posted september 14. I thought I got it right but I used forcePoling instead of log so I give you creds for that. If you don't mind, can I ask you how to go make custom socket.on with parameters? I know how to make a socket.emit with parameters but I find it a little confusing since I'm more on iOS dev and this is actually my first time to use socket. While waiting for our questions to be answered by their web service operator. I would like to try all possible movements I can in this part so I could say that I've already did all that I can. Thank you

Comment: Is this what you mean? Data is received as an array from the server.  From https://github.com/nuclearace/socket.io-client-swift-example :


        self.socket.on("playerMove") {[weak self] data, ack in
            if let name = data[0] as? String, x = data[1] as? Int, y = data[2] as? Int {
                self?.handlePlayerMove(name, coord: (x, y))
            }
        }

Comment: I mean, how do you use a socket.on to pass with parameters? Thank you for the response though. I don't know why but it seems that socket.io for swift is not used as much since I'm really having a hard time looking for references.